# Share Latex's own bibliography example not working

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the share latex own example given on their website to build a bibliography.

Here is my main.tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{sample.bib}

    \begin{document}
    Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{1} 
    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

and here is my sample.bib file

```
@article{1,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}
```

I do this and the thing outputted as a reference in the document is whatever I have out in \cite{}.

Why is this not working?

I get an error now, It says

```
cannot find 'mybibliography.bib'!
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have biblatex and biber installed?

Comment: @roffe I am using share latex

Comment: The code works just fine (https://www.sharelatex.com/project/521ccc3fe1f4b692043d197d), are you doing this locally, or on ShareLaTeX? If locally, you need to make sure that you run `biber` in between runs of pdfLaTeX, see e.g. [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Comment: I am doing it on share latex

Comment: Does https://www.sharelatex.com/project/521ccc3fe1f4b692043d197d work for you? Can you see any differences between that and your own project?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oops, I was looking at your sharelatex and edited the cite command (since it was referring to a non-existent entry); now I am wondering if you meant for it to be like that! Just a heads up.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it works when I click on your link but not when I run mine on sharelatex even though they are exactly the same. I have included the error command which comes up now

Comment: @WillieWong If the code there was anything different to what is given in the question (`\cite{1}`), then I must have changed it by accident, so thanks!

Comment: Is your `.bib` file called `mybibliography.bib`? Is it in the same folder as the `.tex` file?

Comment: I don't understand anything. I too got no bibliography for a while, and then I did something else for a while, and now it works.

It won't work unless the file name of the bibliography is `sample.bib`, of course.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.     My .bib file is called sample.bib

Comment: Then you need of course `\addbibresource{sample.bib}` as well, judging by the error message you posted you have used `\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}`.

Comment: not the cause of the error but don't use numbers as cite keys `\cite{1} ` is going to be very confusing once there are more references and it gets numbered 27 or whatever.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I checked, I did have \addbibresource{sample.bib} but it still does not work.

Comment: Are you willing to let us have access to your project so we can see?

Comment: Is there any news here? No helper was able to reproduce the issue.